# How can I stop my TDrawGrid fixed rows from disappearing when I have no non fixed rows?

Tags: delphi

I have this problem with TDrawGrid with fixed rows (although same applies to fixed cols).

If you have .FixedRows = 1, and decrement the value of .RowCount, when it gets to 1, the .FixedRows automatically gets set to 0, and your fixed rows turn white instead of the usual grey - except in column zero.

Can I stop this from happening? Is this a bug in TDrawGrid?

I realise I can put some code into OnDrawCell to check the rowcount and make paint some fake fixed rows for it if necessary, but I was hoping not to have to do this way.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As designed in the VCL code, it's a "feature" :-) :

```
procedure TCustomGrid.SetRowCount(Value: Longint);
begin
  if FRowCount <> Value then
  begin
    if Value < 1 then Value := 1;
    if Value <= FixedRows then FixedRows := Value - 1; // <= **@#$#@#$**
    ChangeSize(ColCount, Value);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: and it's a private, non-virtual method (in D6 at least) so it can't be easily overridden.

Comment: Thanks gents this looks promising. I was just using a straight TDrawGrid...now I got a TCustomGrid going and overrode DrawCell only, and added the above proc. Its complaining about FRowCount and ChangeSize. Got any tips? I am a bit of a noob....

Comment: Ah OK im an idiot as already stated. Thats the TCustomGrid source already you posted! :( Doh. What do reckon is best to do? Just paint 'fake' ones in DrawCell event?

Comment: if you already have an onDrawCell event, you can use it for ensuring the FixedRows and RowCount do not fall down too much:
`  with Sender as TDrawGrid do
    if FixedRows < 1 then
    begin
      RowCount := 2;
      FixedRows := 1;
    end;`

Comment: Yes I could do that too, Thanks. This VCL 'Feature' is pretty disappointing :(